# Laravel route variables with multiple "-"

Tags: laravel

So I've got a category route in my laravel application looking like this:

```
Route::get('all-{category}-listings', 'CategoryController@index')->name('category');
```

When I go to the following URL localhost:8000/all-test-listings, it works fine,
but when a category also has a hyphen in it's name it gives me a 404, for example localhost:8000/all-test-test-listings

Does anyone know a way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "Regular Expression Constraints" on your route to enable categories with a dash:

```
Route::get('all-{category}-listings', 'CategoryController@index')
->where('category', '[A-Za-z0-9-]+')
->name('category');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints

Comment: For anyone wondering why this still doesn't work, enter `php artisan route:cache` after every change to `web.php`.

Answer (score 0):

> If you would like a route parameter to always be constrained by a
>   given regular expression, you may use the pattern method. You should
>   define these patterns in the boot method of your
>   `RouteServiceProvider`:

```
/**
 * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Route::pattern('category', '[a-z0-9-]+');

    parent::boot();
}
```

> Once the pattern has been defined, it is automatically applied to all
>   routes using that parameter name:

```
Route::get('all-{category}-listings', function ($category) {
    // {category} has to be alpha numeric (lowercase), but can include a dash
});
```